# Change default url to plugin custom post type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, plugins-url

I have a custom post type in my plugin "Luckydraw" as 'voucher'.

By clicking on post link, wordpress generates its URL as :

```
http://localhost:81/luckydraw/index.php/voucher/testing-2/
```

But I want to change it to:

```
http://localhost:81/luckydraw/voucher/testing-2/
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Is your installation inside a subdirectory named `luckydraw`? What is the root of your WordPress installation?

Comment: Yes it is inside the luckydraw menu. That is luckydraw plugin menu.

Comment: So just to be clear your WordPress installation is located at http://localhost:81/luckydraw/? I know not of any menus. When I mean root, I mean the frontpage of the WP installation, ignoring anything else hosted on your server, aka you have a folder called luckydraw containing a WP install, that you've an admin folder at http://localhost:81/luckydraw/wp-admin, etc, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes exactly. ... luckydraw is my plugin name so my folder hirarchy is look like this C:\xampp\htdocs\luckydraw\wp-content\plugins\lucky-draw

Comment: Thanks that clears up a lot of confusion, most of the answers below are working on the premise that you've installed WordPress at localhost:81/ not in the subfolder `luckydraw`, your wording implies that your plugin adds a `luckydraw` rewrite rule, which is not accurate

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow your question, title seems different from question itself.

You seem to want to get rid of `index.php` in URL?

It's hard to say confidently from outside, but it looks like [PATHINFO permalink](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#PATHINFO:_.22Almost_Pretty.22).

If that's the case you would need to change your WP permalink configuration to more common "pretty" one. Doesn't have anything to do with CPT's config.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, but it would be clearer if it showed a screenshot of the permalinks page with the option selected

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your task in both ways through plugin as well as coding

**Manually**

Please see the documentation on [URLs of Namespaced Custom Post Types Identifiers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#URLs_of_Namespaced_Custom_Post_Types_Identifiers). One of the options available to you is to add a `'rewrite'` argument to [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). From the docs:

**Plugin**

Custom Post Type Permalinks allow you edit the permalink structure of custom post type.

Download Link: [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)

Answer (score -1):

Change or add the 
`'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => 'luckydraw', 'with_front' => false ),`
into the **register_post_type** arguments, This will change the slug of your custom post type.

Comment: Dear firend, thank you for the reply, but this is not the case.

Comment: Than can you please explain in brief so i can help you thanks

Comment: Yes, when we create a post then WP automatically generates a slug; in my case it generates a slug like- http://localhost:81/luckydraw/index.php/voucher/testing-2/ ; But i need to change it to :- http://localhost:81/luckydraw/voucher/testing-2/ ; in other way i can say i have to run plugin file by default not theme file that's idex.php

Comment: Ok, now first of all change the permalink to post name and add the default wordpress  .htaccess file this will remove index.php and you will get your desired slug, thanks